# What's point of http only cookies?

Tags: http, security, cookies, xss, csrf

Assume you have XSS attack on your site.
Hacker can make any request with cookies.
So, what's point to hide this value from client?

Answer (score 2):

In an XSS attack, "hackers can make any request with cookies", but **NOT all cookies**. If one cookie is `HttpOnly`, it cannot be accessed  by client JavaScript, which means hackers cannot read the cookie value and send it to his own server, not even know whether this cookie exist.

Normally, when `HttpOnly` is used to protect cookie, the cookie's `Domain` is also set (if `Domain` is missing in HTTP response's `Set-Cookie` header, browser will set the cookie's domain as that HTTP connection's hostname). Hackers can trigger HTTP request and make browser put `HttpOnly` cookie in the request, but it would be restricted by cookie's `Domain` -- the cookie is sent only when its `Domain` match the HTTP request. Thus, `HttpOnly` cookie with website's `Domain` is safe, it will not be leaked to XSS attackers.

Comment: He doesn't need to know cookie value, he just makes request and browser put it to request.

Comment: @Vova yes, browser will put `HttpOnly` cookie in HTTP request. But normally cookie will have a `Domain` attribute, which restrict the cookies sent in the request. For an `HttpOnly` cookie with website's `Domain`, an XSS attacker can only trigger HTTP request and send that cookie to the website server. He/She is not able to send that cookie to his/her own server, which keeps the cookie safe.

Comment: Exist an attack to bypass the httponly flag, Cross-Site Tracing (XST). It consits on do a TRACE request and get the cookie from answer in javascript. Obviously, it happens if the web server has the TRACE method available.

Comment: @sinkmanu The good new is: Modern browsers now prevent TRACE requests being made via JavaScript. Please check https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing

Comment: @shaochuancs Happy to read it. Do you know if exist a table or similar with the browser that support it?

Comment: @sinkmanu sorry but I can't find any list or table that describes which browser have the feature. As XST is found in 2003, I guess nowadays most of the browsers are safe on this topic.

Comment: @shaochuancs regarding your first comment: how does this solve the issue? Value of cookie isn't that important, attack can still hijack the cookie itself.  It doesn't care about knowing the value, just that the end server receives the correct value. HttpOnly doesn't seem to prevent this.

Comment: @shaochuancs If you have an XSS vulnerability, malicious JS code can send requests from the allowed domain. Which is the front end of your application containing malicious JS.

Answer (score 0):

Well Http Only cookies can only be accessed by the server. They cannot be accessed from JavaScript. Which means it will be more difficult for hackers to use these cookies for their own use.

Http Only cookies reduces the possibility of Cross Site Scripting attacks on websites.

See this link for more information: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly